# I am having trouble displaying images for prediction data. ValueError: Expected image array to have rank 3 (single image). Got array with shape: ()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset, prediction

[image]Here I am trying to display the prediction data and the image along with it. But I am struggling quite allot to solve this. I am expecting this to show a random image from the prediction and show if it a normal xray or the other.

I have tried allot to show this data accurately. sometimes I have succeeded in showing the image data (but only from the test data) and I have mainly struggled to show the outcome of that prediction. furthermore I came across this code as shown above but I am having trouble fixing it. I am very unsure what to do.

Comment: array_to_img expects a numpy array containing image data, you are passing 224 as value, which makes no sense.

Comment: A good question contains reproduce-able code which can help you to grab more attention and solutions

Answer (score 0):

you can create dataset and use dataset.shuffle() for random input, please follow the templates that are easy. You can do more experiments by adding

1. Random sequences
2. Image augmentations
3. Multiple dataset, larger input, different image types
4. Masking or other techniques

Sample: dataset input shuffles

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(n)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(3, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(10, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
```

Sample: << Input data, random input create a more reliable working process but not always. Larger dataset the model need to working for the same >>

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
PATH = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Pikaploy', '*.tif')
PATH_2 = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Candidt Kibt', '*.tif')
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH)
files_2 = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH_2)

list_file = []
list_file_actual = []
list_label = []
list_label_actual = [ 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt' ]
for file in files.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    list_file.append(image)
    list_label.append(1)
    
for file in files_2.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    list_file.append(image)
    list_label.append(9)

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
loggings = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\loggings.log"

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)
    
log_dir = checkpoint_dir

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(tf.cast(list_file, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(10, 1, 32, 32, 4), dtype=tf.int64),tf.constant(list_label, shape=(10, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 32, 32, 4 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2.),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6.),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 225)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Callback
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class custom_callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        if( logs['accuracy'] >= 0.95 ):
            self.model.stop_training = True
    
custom_callback = custom_callback()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
    name='Nadam'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: FileWriter
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
if exists(checkpoint_path) :
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
    print("model load: " + checkpoint_path)
    input("Press Any Key!")

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit( dataset, batch_size=100, epochs=10000, callbacks=[custom_callback] )
model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)

plt.figure(figsize=(5,2))
plt.title("Actors recognitions")
for i in range(len(list_file)):
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
        list_file[i],
        data_format=None,
        scale=True
    )
    img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
    plt.subplot(5, 2, i + 1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(list_file_actual[i])
    plt.xlabel(str(round(score[tf.math.argmax(score).numpy()].numpy(), 2)) + ":" +  str(list_label_actual[tf.math.argmax(score)]))
    
plt.show()

input('...')
```

Output:
[image: Sample]